# Tensorflow GPU installation with NVidia T1200 Laptop GPU

Tags: tensorflow, fedora

The NVidia driver is correctly installed.

```bash
$ lspci -nn | grep '\[03'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation TigerLake-H GT1 [UHD Graphics] [8086:9a60] (rev 01)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation TU117GLM [T1200 Laptop GPU] [10de:1fbc] (rev a1)
$ glxinfo | egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer"
egrep: warning: egrep is obsolescent; using grep -E
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: NVIDIA T1200 Laptop GPU/PCIe/SSE2
```

Cuda is also installed :

```bash
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jun_13_19:16:58_PDT_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.2, V12.2.91
Build cuda_12.2.r12.2/compiler.32965470_0
```

But Tensorflow can't correctly view Cuda driver :

```py
Python 3.11.5 (main, Aug 28 2023, 00:00:00) [GCC 13.2.1 20230728 (Red Hat 13.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
2023-10-14 15:28:31.670384: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9342] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
2023-10-14 15:28:31.670413: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:609] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
2023-10-14 15:28:31.670433: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1518] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2023-10-14 15:28:31.674741: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX512F AVX512_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-10-14 15:28:32.201407: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
```

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance